# OrientDB vertex relationships efficient search

Tags: java, search, orientdb

I am new to OrientDB and have these questions:
-   Is there any more efficient way to get the relationships for a given entity than this method:

```
    Iterable<Edge> vet1 = first_vertex.getEdges(Direction.valueOf("BOTH"));
     for (Edge edge : vet1)  
       System.out.println(edge);
```

- Should I parse the result edge e.g., [#9:526597-is_a->#9:8151] by myself to get for example this result: A is_a -> B ?

I should directly get the vertex names (also relationship type and direction) instead of getting only ids and then search for vertex names.

I have a solution but maybe there is faster than it is:

```
    System.out.println(edge.getVertex(Direction.valueOf("OUT")).getProperty("name").toString() + edge.getLabel() + edge.getVertex(Direction.valueOf("IN")).getProperty("name").toString());
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Iterable<Vertex> vet1=first_vertex.getVertices(Direction.BOTH, null);
for (Vertex v : vet1)  
System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: here I will get only the vertexes but I need the relation type, relation direction (in or out). Some thing like:

A is_a -> B, B is_a  <- C, . . . ., . . . .

Comment: I think that your solution
Iterable<Edge> vet1 = first_vertex.getEdges(Direction.valueOf("BOTH"));
     for (Edge edge : vet1)  
       System.out.println(edge.getVertex(Direction.valueOf("OUT")).getProperty("name").toString() + edge.getLabel() + edge.getVertex(Direction.valueOf("IN")).getProperty("name").toString());
is the most correct solution.